# how to sscanf this string

Tags: c, scanf

how can I sscanf the following string

empty(1)

empty(20)

I tried the following but always failed

```
int count;
sscanf(buf, "%*s(%d)", &count)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: empty(1) and empty(20)? what are these

Comment: It's the strings he wants to sscanf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
sscanf(buf, "%*[^(](%d", &count);
```

Answer (score 0):

sscanf always read in the format u have given.

Your test string is empty(1) but in the sscanf u used `sscanf(buf, "%*s(%d)", &count)`

By this way u are trying to copy "empty" to count which will always fail since you cannot assign string to int.

do something like,

```
int count;
char s[20];
sscanf(buf, "%*s(%d)",s, &count)
```

Comment: you have to allocate memory for s first

Comment: @BobAlmond - I will always refers this site http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm
and there is no such definition of this. I think u understood wrongly..

Comment: This is obviously wrong, even your "reference" says: `This is an optional starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored, i.e. it is not stored in the corresponding argument.`. Also, please use a proper reference like http://en.cppreference.com/ or refer to the standard, as these focus on having the current standard definition, not on tutorials. Your site doesn't even really mention the various C-standards which have been released until now.

Comment: This will _not_ work.  The `*` suppresses assignment.  C11 spec "The format shall be ... After the %, the following appear in sequence ... An optional assignment-**suppressing** character *."

Answer (score 0):

If the text will always be "empty(*some int*)" then

```
int count;
int n=0;
if (sscanf(buf, "empty(%d)%n", &count, &n) == 1) && (n > 0)) Success();
```

`sscanf()` will match `char` for `char`  (white-space handled differently though)  until it reaches `"%d"`, then it will try to match an `int`.  Scanning continues, matching `char` for `char` until `"%n"` which saves the scanned `char` count to `n`.

Testing the return value against 1 (1 argument scanned, %n args do not contribute) and seeing that `n` is no longer 0, the scan is known to have *completely* finished.

Could use if code needed to insure nothing *extra* followed.

```
if (sscanf(buf, "empty(%d)%n", &count, &n) == 1) && (buf[n] == '\0')) Success();
```